# "Data argument not used by format string" with printf

Tags: c, printf

I get a "Data argument not used by format string" error when I compile the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int kor[3], eng[3];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("1번째 학생 성적 입력 \n", i+1);  // error shows up for this line
        printf("국어 : "); scanf("%d",&kor[i]);
        printf("\n영어 : "); scanf("%d",&eng[i]);
    }
    printf("=== 학생 성적 출력 ===\n");
    printf("학번 국어 영어 \n");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("%d  %d  %d \n",i, kor[i], eng[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: printf("1번째 학생 성적 입력 \n", i+1);     //Data argument not used by format string

Comment: Possibly `printf("1번째 학생 성적 입력 \n", i+1);` -> `printf("1번째 학생 성적 입력 %d\n", i+1);`. I have no idea what the meaning of the korean text is, so the `%d` might need to go somewhere else in the format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("1번째 학생 성적 입력 \n", i+1);
```

You have provided an argument `i + 1` to `printf()` but it has no corresponding format specifier, so it goes unused.

From the C11 standard:

> [...] If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess
> arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored [...]